# Wall collision validation from an accelerated ball - JavaScript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

I'm currently making a labyrinth ball game using Javascript. Firstly, I draw a maze image onto the canvas. The maze looks like this:

[image]

Then I have an accelerated ball (x,y parameter using `navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration` function and drawn every 33.3 ms using `RequestAnimationFrame`). The hardest part is making a validation for the **wall collision**.

Here is the code:

```
    function draw(){
            switch(state)
            {
                case 'start' :
                    posX=150; //start pos of the ball
                    posY=30;
                    drawStart();
                break;
                case 'initgame' :
                    initGame();
                break;
                case 'game':
                    drawGame(); //draw the image canvas 
                    update(acceleration);
                break;
                case 'end':
                    drawEnd();
                break;  
            }
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    };

    function update(acceleration){
            animate(posX+(acceleration.x)*10, posY(acceleration.y)*10);
    };

    function checkCollision(x,y) {
        var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            //get 5x5 pixels data of next position of the ball  
        var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 5,5); 
        var pix = imgd.data; //pix is 5x5x4=100 array length 
        for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
            if (pix[i] == 0) //first of every four arrays is "black(0,0,0,255)"
                            {
                        collision = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

    function animate(newX, newY){
            var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

            drawGame(); //draw the image canvas

            posX=newX;  
            posY=newY;

            checkCollision(posX,posY);

            if(collision==1)
            {
                //hit wall, need proper code
            }
            else{
                            //move freely
                context.moveTo(posX,posY);
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(posX, posY, 5, 0,2*Math.PI),false;
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle='green';
                context.fill()
                context.lineWidth=5;
                context.strokeStyle='#003300';
                context.stroke();
    }
```

I need a proper code when the ball hits the wall. Logically, example, if the ball hits vertical wall, and the player accelerates the x position (up and down), the ball still moves (up or down) but the y position sticks to the wall.

What should I do? Thanks for the appreciated help and attention!

Comment: You're definitely going to need to check for vertical or horizontal collision before anything.

Comment: See if this helps.... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-html5-game8/